# Some issue defining callbacks

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am very new to .NET programming, and am facing some issues with my code (probably trivial ones).
I am working on a demo app for video recording on WP8.
I require a callback after every frame capture.

My code is as below:

```
private AudioVideoCaptureDevice captureDevice;

startcameraPreview()
{
    var res = AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back)[0];
    captureDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, res);
    captureDevice.PreviewFrameAvailable += new Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler<object, EventArgs>(VideoPreviewFrameAvailable);
    // NOTE: PreviewFrameAvailable is supposed to be a callback.
}

public void VideoPreviewFrameAvailable(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     return;
}
```

On compiling the above, I get the error:

`No overload for 'VideoPreviewFrameAvailable' matches delegate 'Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler<object,System.EventArgs>'`

Please guide me on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: It is because of contravariance in delegate , explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. What you can do is , convert to captureDevice.PreviewFrameAvailable += new Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler<object, RoutedEventArgs>(VideoPreviewFrameAvailable); and public void VideoPreviewFrameAvailable(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

Your types do not match, try

public void VideoPreviewFrameAvailable(object sender, EventArgs e)

In your original handler you have a RoutedEventArgs , but the handler requires EventArgs.

Normally the best way to create the handler method is after typing "+=" and select the entry in the intellisense that starts with "new" and then just press tab or enter 2 times. (If you are using Sharp Develop or Visual Studio)

Comment: Thanks. That's a correct observation. Actually my original code had EventArgs instead of RoutedEventArgs. This issue crept in while copying the code to StackOverflow. I have corrected my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the actual reason.

It was because PreviewFrameAvailable expected a different arguement type `<ICameraCaptureDevice, object>`

```
captureDevice.PreviewFrameAvailable += new Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler<ICameraCaptureDevice, object>(VideoPreviewFrameAvailable);

public void VideoPreviewFrameAvailable(ICameraCaptureDevice a, object b)
{
    nFrameCount++;
}
```

The above works out.